# Laravel Revisionable - Tracking of "Form Input Array"

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, revisionable

I'm currently using the Revisionable Package v1.28.0 for Laravel v5.4.23 which is a great couple for the most situations.

But now I got a little problem with the revisioning of input arrays. The input element `<input name="company_list[]">` is not a big deal but its kind of invisible for the revisionable package. So no changes are written to the database. A `dd()` of the request shows the content of the input fields.

```
"company_list" => array:3 [0 => "12", 1 => "10",2 => "2"]
```

The input array will be synchronized with the User Model.

```
$user->companies()->sync($request->input('company_list',[]))
```

Is there a way to get the changes and translate the ids to the specific names?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Syncing should set the new list. So if you have a name field in the companies table then you could do `$user->companies()->pluck('name')` to get the new company name list.

Answer (score 0):

Currently `revisionable` isn't supporting **Many To Many** relations.
But I solved this problem with the following codes:

```
/**
 * Make revision and sync for many to many relations
 *
 * @param string $relation
 * @param array $list
 * @return array
 */
public function doSync($relation, $list)
{
    $rel = $this->{$relation}();
    $old = $rel->pluck('id')->implode(',');
    $rel->sync($list);
    $new = $rel->pluck('id')->implode(',');
    storePivotRevision($this, $relation, $old, $new);
}

/**
 * Store revision for pivot tables
 *
 * @param string $relation
 * @param string $old
 * @param string $new
 * @return null
 */
function storePivotRevision($relation, $old, $new)
{
    if ($old == $new) {
        return;
    }
    DB::table('revisions')->insert([
        'revisionable_type' => get_class($this),
        'revisionable_id' => $model->id,
        'user_id' => auth()->check() ? auth()->user()->id : null,
        'key' => "{$relation}_pivot",
        'old_value' => $old,
        'new_value' => $new,
        'created_at' => now(),
        'updated_at' => now(),
    ]);
}
```

Now instead of 
`$user->roles()->sync([1, 2, 3, ...]);`

you can use 
`$user->doSync('roles', [1, 2, 3, ...]);`

The code is written generally for all models (not specified to one), so you can put them inside a `trait` and call it like this:
$model->doSync('many_to_many_relation', $listArray);

Hope this helps :)